# convert date to T Z format

Tags: php, date

My date format is something like this

```
2013-05-07 18:56:57 (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss)
```

I want the output as following.

```
2013-05-07T06:17:55.827Z
```

Is there a simple way than using big functions ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should give the proper ISO8601 date/time in Z(ulu) timezone:

```
str_replace('+00:00', 'Z', gmdate('c'))
```

To do a date conversion:

```
str_replace('+00:00', 'Z', gmdate('c', strtotime('2013-05-07 18:56:57')))
```

To have the additional `.000` (which is useless imho):

```
str_replace('+00:00', '.000Z', gmdate('c', strtotime('2013-05-07 18:56:57')))
```

Comment: where should i pass my date here ??

Comment: @sandy It's the second argument to `gmdate()`.

Comment: i tried it didn't work.. i tried like this str_replace('+00:00', 'Z', gmdate('c','2013-05-07 18:56:57'));

Comment: @sandy You also have to use `strtotime()` then. Updated answer.

Comment: hey..i missed this...hh:mm:ss.000Z...

Comment: @sandy You don't actually need that `.000` to be a valid date/time.

Answer (score 65):

Try this:

```
 date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z", strtotime("2013-05-07 18:56:57"));
```

Comment: can i make that .000 dynamic ?

Comment: The whole idea of the `Z` suffix is that the date is expressed as UTC; `date()` doesn't do that as it takes the local timezone into account.

Comment: Default php data not contain milliseconds, but if you work with current date, you may use microtime() function for get it