# Trying to get current Timestamp with the following format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MSSZ

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, discord

So i am trying to get the current Discord Webhooks's embedded Timestamp with the following format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MSSZ`(PHP) which will result in `2015-12-31T12:00:00.000Z`

What I have done: 
`$timestamp = date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date("H:i:s") . '.';`

But really I couldn't complete that format `MSSZ` which results in `000Z`

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16516254/5447994) still Zulu timezone in php gives 000Z

Comment: Thanks @Thamilan it solves my needs :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display milliseconds (added in PHP 7.0.0) like this.

```
echo date('Y-m-d').'T'.date("H:i:s").'.'.date("v").'Z';
```

wich will output the following:

```
2018-03-08T06:57:24.000Z
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil but Unfortunately iam using PHP 5.6 so that MS date("v") could be replaced with 000 for now

Comment: Sure than that's the best way to do it! :)

Comment: or simply `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z')`

Answer (score -1):

Another code to display milliseconds if using DateTime

`(new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\.v\Z');`