# Convert date-time value to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z format

Tags: php, datetime

I need to convert a datetime string format (2019-04-08 09:39:23) to this format : 2019-04-08T16:14:44.000Z - this is just an example output - I don't know what the actual value is in T-Z.

```
$t = "20190408093923"; # 2019-04-08 09:39:23
echo date("Y-m-dTH:i:sZ", strtotime($t));
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: ISO 8601 date format.

    echo date("c", strtotime($t));

cheers.

Comment: Required format has 16:14:44.000Z at the end. "c" has +05:30

Comment: Got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16516187/7831249

Comment: Yeah simply use str_replace to replace your +05:30 to .000Z in the string

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape any letters that aren't formatting specifications.

```
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime($t));
```